# Bypass Required Lookup Filter Criteria through apex

Tags: apex

Is it possible to bypass a required look up filter criteria through apex? For example for a certain scenario it will not throw the filter criteria but it's still there. Been searching the internet regarding this one, but can't seem to get a clear answer.

For example

My Filter criteria is like this.

```
(Distributor: Account Record TypeEQUALSPartner) AND
(Distributor: Account IDNOT EQUAL TOOpportunity: Primary Partner ID) AND
(Distributor: Partner TypeEQUALSDistributor)
```

Now there is a scenario where in it's allright to have the Distributor : Parner type = null or blank. and it's only applicable for that scenario so addin the null value in the filter criteria is a no no.

If it's not possible to by pass using apex code. Can you give me any idea or workaround regarding this one?

My Code somewhat look like this.

```
Protected List<Opportunity> allOpportunites;
public void createRenewalOpps(){
//add renewalOpps Values
allOpportunities.addAll(renewalOpps.values)
}

public void ManageOpportunities(){
//the filter look up criteria is in the Opportunity object
//error will be thrown in the DML call since in my data the distributor : 
//partner type is blank


upsert allOpportunities; //Error will be thrown
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The most basic solution is to add a "bypass validation" checkbox to your record that no users have access to, which your code can can set to `true` when the validation rule should be bypassed.  Your filter then becomes

```
Distributor: Bypass Filter OR
(
    (Distributor: Account Record TypeEQUALSPartner) AND
    (Distributor: Account IDNOT EQUAL TOOpportunity: Primary Partner ID) AND
    (Distributor: Partner TypeEQUALSDistributor)
)
```